# how to generate a ChAruco board calibration?

Tags: opencv, aruco

how do I generate a ChAruco board calibration? I tried to find an existing board in Google Search but I couldn't find it.

Thanks,
Carlos

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `cv::aruco::CharucoBoard::draw` as described in the [CharucoBoard Class Reference](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d0/d3c/classcv_1_1aruco_1_1CharucoBoard.html) to create an image and then `imwrite` to write the image to a file.

Answer (score 9):

You can generate ChArUco patterns and save them as vector graphics (PDF) here: https://calib.io/pages/camera-calibration-pattern-generator
That way you get the best accuracy in the print possible.

Answer (score 2):

There will be a built-in pattern_generator in opencv_contrib
that place at folder: opencv_contrib/modules/aruco/misc/pattern_generator/

You can use it to generate your marker as vector graphics and print it out.

https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/pull/2250

PS. LOL, I put the tool to official helper scripts/tool, now you guys have no reason to delete my answer XDDD....

Answer (score 1):

Here is a C++ example on how to create and save a Charuco board as an image:

```
#include <opencv2/aruco/charuco.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>

int main(void)
{
  cv::Mat m(700, 500, CV_8UC1);
  cv::Ptr< cv::aruco::Dictionary > dict = cv::aruco::getPredefinedDictionary(cv::aruco::DICT_4X4_50);
  cv::Ptr< cv::aruco::CharucoBoard > charuco = cv::aruco::CharucoBoard::create(7, 5, 0.04, 0.02, dict);
  charuco->draw(cv::Size(700, 500), m, 0, 1);
  cv::imwrite("board.png", m);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Charuco boards (svg format) can be generated here: [MarkrMakr](https://markrmakr.herokuapp.com)

Comment: The link is dead. It say's "There's nothing here, yet."

Answer (score 0):

I have been generating charuco  from https://www.deepen.ai/calibrate. They have the option to save it as pdf or png from there. It has a target generator which generates charuco boards.